# Delete last semicolon of matched line

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with multiple lines. Something like this:

```
Session
PKG_TEST
Call: command(parameter);
Error: error message
end of log;
Session2
PKG_TEST2
Call: command2(parameter2);
Error: error message
end of log;
```

I need to remove the semicolon at the end of each line that starts with Call.

I know how to find every line that starts with `Call` with `/^Call.*/`, but can't make everything in one sed command without deleting every semicolon in the file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a substitution only on lines that match a pattern, you can append the substitution to an address:

```
sed '/^Call/s/;$//' infile
```

This checks if your line matches `^Call`, and if so, it executes `s/;$//`, which removes a trailing semicolon.